# how Can I put the ToolWindow in the middle of IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I am working on a plugin on IntelliJ.

`ToolWindow` on IntelliJ Plugin have a property `anchor` which we can put our `ToolWindow` on `left/right/bottom` of IntelliJ. But I am willing to put a `ToolWindow` or something like that in the middle of IntelliJ(the `editor ToolWindow` place), just as the picture shows. How can I do it on IntelliJ?

Or How the `editor ToolWindow` do like that? I am trying find how `IntelliJ` do in source code but got nothing.

I would appreciated if any help useful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle area of the IntelliJ user interface is always occupied by editor tabs. An editor tab is not a toolwindow, and it's not possible to place a toolwindow in the middle of the UI.

You can place your own component in an editor tab if you implement the `FileEditorProvider` interface.

Comment: Thank you very much. Further question about it. I already implement `FileEditorProvider` and put it into `plugin.xml` as `<fileEditorProvider implementation="MyFileEditor" />`, but how can I make `MyFileEditor` visable? Is there any doc or open link about it? Thanks again.